# mkdir, file_exists : confusing and paradoxal errors

Tags: php, mkdir, file-exists

The following code gives me the error : "mkdir : file exists".

```
    $path = 'c://wamp/www/et1/other';
    $new_location = 'c://wamp/www/et1/other/test';
    if(file_exists($path) && is_dir($path))
    {
        if(!file_exists($new_location))
        {               
            mkdir($new_location, 0777);
        }
    }
```

However, if I don't put the second if condition, it gives me the error : "mkdir : no such file or directory". Also if I add recursivity by writting mkdir($new_location,077,true) I don't get errors but the directory is not created. I just don't understand what I could be doing wrong here.

Comment: Are `$path` and `$new_location` related? If so, how? If not, why do you mention both?

Comment: Can you please post values for $path and $new_location ?

Comment: `mkdir($new_location, 0777, true);` assuming `$new_location` is `$path.$some_new_directory`

Comment: Impossible to answer without guessing http://sscce.org/. This is not a simple logic problem.

Comment: what is `$new_location`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by the double slashes in your paths, which PHP doesn't like at all. If you change `c://` to `c:/` it will all work just fine.

And by the way, there's no real reason to specify the `0777` as the mode because that's also the default.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that `$new_location` is the current path `$path` with a new directory name appended. you will need to `mkdir` with the recursive flag set to true, so that it `Allows the creation of nested directories specified in the pathname.`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php

```
mkdir($new_location, 0777, true);
```

Comment: you could do away with th outer logic check in that instance

Comment: good point, went copy/paste mad...

Answer (score 0):

The error is self explanatory

```
Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: No such file or directory in
```

It means that the parent directory does not exist  .. you need to add  recursive option to create `parent directory` then the `current directory`

```
  mkdir($new_location, 0777, true);
```

If you don't want to do that always check if parent directory exist

```
if (!is_dir(dirname($new_location)) || !is_writable(dirname($new_location)))
{
    trigger_error("Your parent does not exist");
}
```